# Understanding Extended Euclid Algorithm

Tags: linear-programming, number-theory

I have some (say, n) marbles (small glass balls) and I am going to buy some boxes to store them. The boxes are of two types:

```
Type 1: each box costs c1 Taka and can hold exactly n1 marbles
Type 2: each box costs c2 Taka and can hold exactly n2 marbles
```

I want each of the used boxes to be filled to its capacity and also to minimize the total cost of buying them. Since I find it difficult for me to figure out how to distribute my marbles among the boxes, I seek your help. I want your program to be efficient also.

```
Input
```

The input file may contain multiple test cases. Each test case begins with a line containing the integer n (1 <= n <= 2,000,000,000). The second line contains c1 and n1, and the third line contains c2 and n2. Here, c1, c2, n1 and n2 are all positive integers having values smaller than 2,000,000,000.

A test case containing a zero for n in the first line terminates the input.

```
Output
```

For each test case in the input print a line containing the minimum cost solution (two nonnegative integers m1 and m2, where mi = number of Type i boxes required) if one exists, print "failed" otherwise.

If a solution exists, you may assume that it is unique.

```
Sample Input
43
1 3
2 4
40
5 9
5 12
0

Sample Output
13 1
failed
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried - this isn't a "write this program for me" service. However, to restate your problem in minimal terms, you want to find a minimal value of `x * c1 + y * c2` subject to the constraint that `x * n1 + y * n2 == n`... (and obviously, `x >= 0`, `y >= 0`...)

Comment: How do I find if there exists integral values of x and y such that x * n1 + y * n2 == n is satisfied.

Comment: Perhaps by iterating `x` from 0 to `floor(n/n1)` and seeing if the solution to `y = (n - x * n1) / n2` is an integer? Basic algebra, really...

Comment: You should take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming.